# System.IO.Directory search pattern not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net

I am attempting to retrieve `jpeg` and `jpg` files using the following statement:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(someDirectoryPath, "*.jp?g");
```

MSDN's [docs for System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(string, string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) state that `?` represents "Exactly zero or one character.", however the above block selects `jpeg` files but omits `jpg` files.

I am currently using the overly-permissive search pattern `"*.jp*g"` to achieve my results, but it wrinkles my brain because it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs you linked to:

> A searchPattern with a file extension of one, two, or more than three characters returns only files having extensions of exactly that length that match the file extension specified in the searchPattern.

I suspect that's the problem. To be honest, I'd probably fetch *all* the files and then postprocess them in code - it'll make for code which is simpler to reason about than relying on the Windows path-handling oddities.

Comment: @svick: Agreed - but it does go to show that the whole thing is a bit bizarre around the number of characters in the extension. This is why I suggested postprocessing instead :)

Comment: AFAIK `?` matches exactly one character and `*` matches anything (including *zero characters*)...

Comment: @Jon: Thanks. I'll try to read those yellow notes in the future rather than presuming rational behaviour. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use `"*"` as a pattern and process the result yourself OR use

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(someDirectoryPath, "*.jpg").Union (Directory.GetFiles(someDirectoryPath, "*.jpeg")).ToArray();
```

According to [the Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) the pattern you use would return only files with extensions which are 4 characters long.

[MSDN reference on `Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx)